# Update Field Geometry Polygon PostGIS PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, geometry, sql-update, postgis

I am having some trouble trying to update a field.

I created a column as `text` and stored many rows with `(lon,lat)`. Now I have created one more field as `Geometry(Polygon)` and I am trying to update it unsuccessfully.

The data is stored like this:

```
POLYGON ((-16.6318775869111 -52.5925428149806, -16.6346393504709 -52.572542814981
        , -16.629462102066 -52.5525428149806, -16.6255191065928 -52.5455420519144
        , -16.6055191065928 -52.5488828022871, -16.6021791014778 -52.552542814981
        , -16.6108484688169 -52.5925428149806, -16.6255191065928 -52.599495926874
        , -16.6318775869111 -52.5925428149806))
```

I am trying this command

```
UPDATE field_as_text 
   SET field_as_geomtry = SELECT ST_GeomFromText(SELECT field_as_text);
```

I am getting this error message

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "select"
LINE 1: ... set field_as_geomtry = select (ST...
```

Could anyone enlighten me?

Answer (score 4):

You need to start by reading [the manual about the SQL `UPDATE` command](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-update.html).
Should look something like this:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET    field_as_geomtry = ST_GeomFromText(field_as_text);
```